# Middleware auth except throwing error method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I want the views: `listings` and `showlisting` pages, to be displayed for guests (without being logged in).

When using:

```
$this->middleware('auth';
```

In the construct function of my `ListingsController` everything works (for logged in users), but when I exclude index and show methods by using:

```
$this->middlware('auth')->except('index','show');
```

I get this error:

> BadMethodCallException Method
>   App\Http\Controllers\ListingsController::middlware does not exist.

I have searched for a few days, and I haven't found any solution.

**ListingsController.php**

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middlware('auth')->except('index', 'show');
}
```

**web.php (route file)**

```php
Route::get('/', 'ListingsController@index');
Route::resource('listings', 'ListingsController');
Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
Auth::routes();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
$this->middlware('auth')->except('index', 'show');
```

Middleware is misspelled and your error reflects that. It should be:

```php
$this->middleware('auth')->except(['index', 'show']);
```

Comment: OH!! Thanks too much I really do not know how that happned!?